# ¿Cómo definir el periodo y frecuencia?

Tags: python

Hola estoy practicando con Python, y quisiera saber como puedo generar un plot básico de la función seno, pero definiendo la frecuencia y el periodo manualmente:

Una idea de mi código seria lo mas clásico:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = np.sin(np.arange(0,1000,1))

plt.plot(x)

plt.show()
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: Cuál es tu pregunta sobre el código que compartes?

Comment: Si quisiera hacer el plot del seno manipulando manualmente los periodos y la frecencia

Comment: Hm, la función seno está bien definida en frecuencia (y por lo tanto, en período, que son variables dependientes). Una sinusoidal es entonces lo que buscas graficar

Comment: exacto en si deseo manipular a voluntad la frecuencia o el periodo a voluntad, para graficar

Comment: Como sugerencia, procura aceptar alguna respuesta (así sea la tuya propia) en tus preguntas. Tienes UNA con respuesta aceptada. Eso poco motiva a que te ayuden...

Comment: Como es eso podrías explicarme, no entiendo muy bien el sistema de la pagina habré hecho click en algún lado.

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta rápidamente. :)

Comment: Rocker: aceptar la respuesta es marcarla como válida. De esta forma marcas que la respuesta sirve a lo que preguntas. Y como indica @Alfabravo, motiva a que te ayuden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te indicaba en los comentarios, usar la función `sin()` a secas no da muchas opciones, pues la función está claramente definida en período -2*pi si no me falla la memoria- (y por ello mismo, en frecuencia, que es 1/período).

Para poder hacer lo que buscas, hay que identificar primero la función que se debe graficar (es casi que lo único que hay que cambiar). Así pues, de nuevo si la memoria no falla, una onda sinusoidal se puede representar como

`y = A sin(B(x + C)) + D`

Donde:

- Amplitud es A
- Período es 2π/B
- Desplazamiento de Fase es C (valor positivo la corre a la izquierda)
- Desplazamiento vertical es D

EN esta fórmula puede replicarse el caso base, `sin(x)`, usando A = 1, B = 1, C = 0 y D = 0.

Un ejemplo (que no he podido probar) sería más o menos:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Eje X con numeritos espaciados
x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,100)

# Las variables de la ecuacion
A=1
B=1
C=0
D=0

# La función va en Y como toda la vida. y = A sin(B(x + C)) + D
# sin(x) es el caso con A = 1, B = 1, C = 0 y D = 0.
# No entendí por qué la pintabas en X...

y = A*np.sin(B(x + C)) + D

# Ejes en el centro
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

# Pintar
plt.plot(x,y, 'b-')

# Mostrar
plt.show()
```